# Расширение и настройки для отправки электронных писем на электронные почты от лица сервера YII2

Tags: yii2

Необходимо: найти расширение для yii2, которое позволяет отправлять электронные письма с сервера на электронную почту.

Сейчас использую `SwiftMailer` и отсылаю через аккаунт `@gmail.com`, но мне нужно отправлять сообщения именно с моего сервера.

Конфиг:

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'images.tkvprok.ru',
            'username' => 'images.tkvprok.ru',
            'password' => '',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls'
        ]
    ],
```

Может есть какие-нибудь настройки для `SwiftMailer`, чтобы отправлять письма с сервера? Где посмотреть? Как настроить?

Comment: Не пробовали использовать Swift_SendmailTransport?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов, нет, не работает. может нужны какие то конкретные настройки? добавил свои настройки в вопрос.

Comment: какая ошибка возникает при использовании Swift_SendmailTransport? Так же на сервере должен быть установлен sendmail. Если попробовать выполнить простой скрипт mail ("my@email.ru", "Subject", "Text");